# C# get client username from RDP session win form application

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, powershell

How to get the client username thr RDP

Computer A login as domain user "abc/user1"
user1 remote desktop connect to Computer B as domain user "abc\test"

In computer B user 1 open a win form application
win form application need to track which logon user in computer A rdp to it

what I want: winform in Computer B able to display the "abc\user1"

Comment: If you can install software on computer A, I think you could do this via [virtual channels](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383509(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This won't be possible as the `mstsc.exe`'s user context on ComputerA is not transmitted with the RDP session, only the login credentials of the "User name:" box during login. You can view the PC name and/or IP address of the all connected RDP clients by searching `netstat` output for `3389`. Perhaps that will help you identify the target user.

I don't know the architecture of your application, but it is generally considered bad practice for users to use "service accounts" or "generic logins". Granting domain user `abc\user1` access to RDP to ComputerB will allow you access to the information you need.